How to install a yanked release of opencv-python?
I'm trying to install opencv-python 3.4.2.16 but that version is not available in pip. Is there any way to install that specific version? I'm using  python 3.6.0 in windows.
I have tried using pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16 but it could not find a version.

Download file(s) manually from https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.4.2.16/#files But why exactly that version? Why not 3.4.2.17, for example?

My older code relies on SIFT & SURF features, which are patented and incompatible with newer OpenCV versions. To resolve this, I downgraded to version 3.4.2.16 which resolved the compatibility issues. Everything is running smoothly now. Appreciate your help!

wrong. SIFT's patent expired years ago, so it has been in opencv binary builds ever since that time (and always available if you build it yourself). nobody should be using lesser descriptors (SURF). if you want an alternative to SIFT, use AKAZE or something like that. -- do not use 3.x.
